# Bounding the image size for a function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, probability-distributions, random

Consider a bijective function $f$ from $\{0, 1\}^n$ to $\{0, 1\}^n$.

Now, sample a random $k$ to $1$ function $g$ (that is, from the set of all possible $k$ to $1$ functions from $\{0, 1\}^n$ to $\{0, 1\}^n$, pick one uniformly at random) and compose it with $f$.  Repeat this procedure for $d$ rounds (that is, each time, sample a random $k$ to $1$ function independently and compose it with whatever function we constructed till the previous round.)

I am trying to lower bound the expected image size of the resultant function, where the expectation is taken over the randomness in choosing the functions.

---

My intuition is that the image size will be sufficiently high. I think one way to show this is to calculate the collision probability (the probability that two randomly picked elements in the image of the resultant function are the same) and show that it is sufficiently small.

Comment: 1) Maybe due to my low level in English, I do not understand "sample a random $k$ to $1$ function $g$". 2) please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): include your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: A $k$ to $1$ function is a function where every element in the image set has $k$ distinct pre-images.

Comment: Wlog $f={\rm id}.$ What you are looking for is a lower bound for $|\operatorname{im}(g_1\circ\dots\circ g_d)|$ where $g_1,\dots,g_d$ are $k$ to $1$ functions from $\{0, 1\}^n$ to $\{0, 1\}^n$.

Comment: Does that mean $k$ is a divisor of $2^n$ and so a power of $2$?

Comment: Indeed: $k|\operatorname{im}(g_i)|=2^n.$

Comment: Let $k=2^r.$ If $d>\lfloor n/r\rfloor,$ $|\operatorname{im}(g_1\circ\dots\circ g_d)|$ can be equal to $1.$

Comment: Yes, it could be, for certain choices of functions. But is it the expected behavior (ie, is this what happens with high probability)? For instance, what happens if I want to calculate the expected value of the size of the image? I have edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: @RandomMatrices What range of parameters are you interested in? For example, are $k$ and $d$ fixed and $n$ is very large compared to them both? Or do you want an exact answer for all $n,k,d$? Can you give a specific choice of $k$ and $d$ (possibly in terms of $n$) that you are interested in?

Comment: k and d are fixed, and n is very large compared to both. Although an exact answer would not hurt!

Comment: @RandomMatrices in the future, at me by writing "@mathworker21" so that I see you have responded. I only just now saw your response.

Comment: Please edit your question so all these conditions are in the comments. They are crucial to the form of the answer. Comments can get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough analysis.

This problem can be restated as follows: Let $N:=2^n$, and suppose that $k$ divides $N$.  Suppose that we start with an urn with $N$ red balls.  Then, take an empty urn, and sample $k$ balls from the first urn without replacement.  If any of these balls are red, we place a red ball in the second urn; otherwise, place a black ball in the second urn.  Now sample $k$ more balls without replacement from the first urn, and do the same thing.  Repeat this until we have taken $N/k$ samples of $k$ balls from the first urn and it becomes empty.  Then add $N(1-1/k)$ black balls to the second urn and discard the first urn.  Call all this one large step, and take $d$ large steps in all.  The number of red balls left at the end behaves in the same way as the desired image size.

Since, according to the comments, $n$ is large (so $N$ is large) we can approximate sampling without replacement by sampling with replacement.  If we do this, we get $d+1$ random variables, $X_0$, $\dots$, $X_d$, where $X_0=N$ and $X_{i+1}$ is the sum of $N/k$ independent random variables, each of which is 1 with probability $1-(1-X_i/N)^k$ and 0 otherwise; that is, $X_{i+1}$ is binomially distributed with parameters $N/k$ and $1-(1-X_i/N)^k$.

For large $N$ we can approximate this further by assuming that each $X_i$ will be close to its mean.  In this case the final answer is $f(d, k) N/k$, where $f(d, k)$ is the result of iterating the function $g_k(z):=1-(1-z/k)^k$ $d$ times, starting at $k$.  Numerically, $f(d, k)$ appears to behave as $\Theta(1/d)$; we have $1\le d f(d, k)\le 4$ for all $1\le d\le 1000$ and $2\le k\le 1000$.